# Find the max value but generate NA if the compared values are equal

Tags: r, max

I have a matrix of prediction results and I want to find the absolute maximum probability in each row of the matrix:

```
   > head(TestResult)
           c290       c320       c390       c460       c520       c580      c710       c780       c800    c100001
[1,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.06666667 0.25000000 0.14285714 0.00000000 0.3333333 0.26666667 0.06666667 0.04545455
[2,] 0.01808511 0.05480869 0.01342282 0.01968504 0.03144654 0.02349336 0.5382199 0.07889344 0.11472081 0.05813953
[3,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.25000000 0.00000000 0.2000000 0.33333333 0.50000000 0.28571429
[4,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
[5,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
[6,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
>
```

As you can see, in the last three rows there is no probability value. So far, my code is:

```
BNpred <- colnames(TestResult)[max.col(TestResult,ties.method = "first")]
BNpred <- substring(BNpred,2)
```

And then for the rows with all equal values, R returns a default class of "290"(see below). While I wish there was an NA there so the default number wouldn't affect the accuracy of my predictor.

```
> head(BNpred)
[1] "710" "710" "800" "290" "290" "290"
```

How should I change my code so that it assigns NA as max whenever all the rows equal zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line:

```
BNpred[rowSums(abs(TestResult)) == 0] <- NA
```

Or this

```
BNpred[!apply(TestResult,1,any)] <- NA
```

Comment: shouldn't it be NA?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper for your answer. Last night I came up with another solution so I'm writing it here for others:

```
for (i in 1:1430){
  if(max(TestResult[i,])==0){

    BNpred[i] = "NA" }}
```